# Navigation in HTML is not working

Tags: html, navigation

I am trying to add navigation to different sections of a page. However, it seems that's not working... I have made plenty of research, but I really cannot get why this code is not working.

Just to note I am a very beginner in front-end development.

This is the navigation:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu"><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and this is where I try to navigate the user:

```
<section id="about">
    <h1>About me</h1>
    <p>some text about me</p>
</section>
```

Is there is something that I am missing?

Here is the [entire code](https://codepen.io/DrSavvina/pen/OOzgKW) in codepen.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't see any problem in code you have posted, it should work.
You can check it out here : https://jsfiddle.net/r5dha5v6/ 
I have pasted your code and added some </br> so you could see that it moves

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sefacosiye/1/edit?html,css,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought to copy/paste my code in codepen and there it works. So, the problem happens when I am actually trying to see the code on the browser.